# I used windows 7 in dual boot with opensuse, I deleted the partition on the opensuse, but how can I delete grub bootloader?

Tags: windows-7, linux, grub, opensuse, bootloader

I already tried using a windows 7 disk for repair, and I tried the bootrec.exe commands in command prompt as well but they don't work, the automatic repair also does not work. Is there any way to remove grub from bios or wherever it is installed without having to format my entire system?

Answer (score 3):

Boot from windows 7 installation DVD. Select 'Repair' on first screen(the one with Install Now  button) and then select your Windows installation and open command prompt from there.

And type:

```
bootrec /RebuildBcd
bootrec /FixMbr
bootrec /FixBoot
```

Here you have complete list of commands: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392/

Answer (score 0):

Try Pinger's methods
If all else fails, go through this article:
http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Recovering+the+Windows+Bootloader+from+the+DVD

and choose the **Option Three: Nuclear Holocaust**..
:P

I was able to fix mine with **Option Two** though.